# Output "But it didn't sing."

Tags: python

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"
print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % (True, False, False, True)
print formatter % (formatter, formatter, formatter, formatter)
print formatter % (
"I had this thing.",
"That you could type up right.",
"But it didn't sing.",
"So I said goodnight."
)
```

In this program, there's no mistake, but just a questioning. Notice that the last line of output uses both single-quotes and double-quotes for individual pieces. Why do you think that is? Why they didn't choose to use double quotes around all the strings

Comment: double quotes can contain single quotes as part of the string and vice versa. That's it.

Comment: FWIW, I had to read this question 3 or 4 times to be able to figure out what you were asking.  It _feels_ to me like you were trying too hard to be "clever" instead of trying hard to be clear.  To make this more clear, I would post the exact output and figure out a way to highlight the line that is confusing to draw attention to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python objects (where feasible) attempt to represent themselves in a way that could be used to reconstruct the object exactly when using `repr`.  Since your format string is `%r` rather than `%s`, you're asking for the string's `repr` instead of it's `str` representation.  For strings with a single quote in them, there are a number of choices that would be valid `repr` representations... A few off the top of my head are:

```
"foo'bar"
'foo\'bar'
"""foo'bar"""
'''foo'bar'''
```

Of these choices, the first version looks the best so that's what they chose to use.  You might ask why they didn't choose to use double quotes around *all* the strings, but then of course you have the same problem with strings that have double quotes ...

Comment: Is there exists a simpler way to write the last line `print formatter % (
"I had this thing.",
"That you could type up right.",
"But it didn't sing.",
"So I said goodnight."
)`

Comment: That's pretty simple ... can you clarify what you mean by "simpler"?

Comment: I would like to obtain simply `I had this thing. That you could type up right.  That you could type up right.  That you could type up right.` (Without simple or double quote)

Comment: Can you `' '.join` it?

Comment: @DavidLabrecque: You told Python to show you the representation of the string by using `%r` for formatting and now you don't want it? Solution: Don't use `%r`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a duplicate and it's because you're using raw representation of string.
So let's see

For this sentence `"I had this thing."` output will be single or double quoted because there is not single/double qoutes inside string, the only string containing double quoted output will be `"But it didn't sing."` because it already contains single quotes inside it :)

If you were using %s , you would see only the string without quotes :)